# Image in Django is no longer showing

Tags: python, html, django

So i am doing a project in Django and I had some images upload and they use to be there just fine. I haven´t go in to the project for a couple of weeks as I was busy and today when I wanted to continue I realise that all the images come with the little x sign or broken in another browser. I am not sure why.

the code I have for the image is this

```
        <h6 style="margin-left: 2.5cm; color: rgba(0, 95, 0, 0.8); ">El Día Que Fleko Se Convirtio En Silver Surfer</h6>
        <a href="{% url 'Fleko' %}">
            <img title="El Día Que Fleko Se Convirtio En Silver Surfer" src="{% static 'TresAcordesApp/img/Fleko.jpg' %}" height="250px" width="300px" style="margin-left: 2.5cm;" alt="">
        </a>
```

This was working just fine up to today. it supposed to be an image that you can click and it takes you to a video. you can still click and it will take you to the video but I can see the image.

THANK YOU very much.
:)

Edit: manage to sorted out the path was wrong, it confused me because it was working fine until it didn’t

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons why your image is not displaying.

1. Make sure, your path `TresAcordesApp/img/Fleko.jpg` is correct and image exist at that location.
2. By default django looks for template inside folder - `your_app/templates`.
3. If you have stored template in any other custom folder, meaning other than `templates` directory then please update `TEMPLATES` setting in settings.py accordingly.

You can refer to django doc more details - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#templates

Answer (score 0):

your image url path might have had issues before left the project, but chrome sometimes hold the image up even when things have already gone wrong, until you try to open your app on another browser.
run your server, use crl-shift-I or f12 to see the path your browser was looking up for your image. the problem will definitely be from your settings.py code.I will also suggest you post your settings.py code.